# How do I string together multiple operations in a calculator?

Tags: javascript

I am building a calculator and I am looking to conduct multiple operations. I have gone through different versions of code (converting variables to arrays for multiple digit operations, implementing 'previousNum' and 'currentNum' instead of 'a' and 'b') to calculate multiple expressions however I don't know how to proceed.

Currently, if I calculate 10 + 20 and press = , I get 30. If I + another 10 and press = I get 40 which is great. However, I am unable to do 10 + 20 + 10 together as I get 30. I also foresee doing multiple operation lines being a problem (10 + 20 * 10)

I would appreciate any modifications to help solve my issue, as well if anyone can point me in the right direction with the logic. I feel I have modified things so much that lots of my code is becoming redundant or inefficient. Thanks!

```js
let button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let screen = document.querySelector(".screen");
let decimal = document.querySelector("[data-type='decimal']");
let userOperator = document.querySelectorAll("[data-type='operator']");
let equals = document.querySelector("[data-type='equals']");
let clear = document.querySelector("[data-type='clear']");
let del = document.querySelector("[data-type='delete']");

let operand = [];
let tempArray = [];
let tempExpressionFiltered = [];
let tempExpression = [];
let previousNum = [];
let currentNum = [];

decimal.addEventListener("click", decimalDisplay);
button.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", buttonDisplay));
button.forEach(numbersClicked => numbersClicked.addEventListener("click", addToExpression));
userOperator.forEach(operatorClicked => operatorClicked.addEventListener("click", chosenOperator));
equals.addEventListener("click", operate);
clear.addEventListener("click", clearScreen);
del.addEventListener("click", deleteNumber);

function clearScreen() {
  screen.innerText = "";
  operand = [];
}

function deleteNumber() {
  screen.innerText = screen.innerText.slice(0, -1);
  operand.pop()
}

function chosenOperator() {
  if (this.innerText == "+") {
    chosenOperator = add;
  } else if (this.innerText == "-") {
    chosenOperator = subtract;
  } else if (this.innerText == "*") {
    chosenOperator = multiply;
  } else if (this.innerText == "/") {
    chosenOperator = divide;
  }
}

function addToExpression() {

  tempExpression.push(this.innerText);

  tempExpressionFiltered = tempExpression.filter(item => !item.includes("+") && !item.includes("-") && !item.includes("*") && !item.includes("/") && !item.includes("=") && !item.includes("clear") && !item.includes("delete") && !item.includes("."))

  if (tempExpressionFiltered.length >= 1) {
    tempArray = tempExpressionFiltered.join("")
  }

  tempArray = parseFloat(tempArray);

  if (tempExpression.includes("+") || tempExpression.includes("-") || tempExpression.includes("*") || tempExpression.includes("/") || tempExpression.includes("=")) {
    //if statement below ensures if user presses an operator twice that 0 isn't passed into operand
    if (tempArray >= 1) {
      operand.push(tempArray);
      tempExpression.length = 0;
      tempExpressionFiltered.length = 0;
      tempArray = 0;

      if (operand.length <= 2) {
        previousNum = operand[0]
        currentNum = operand[1]

      } else {
        previousNum = operand[operand.length - 1];
        currentNum = result
      }
    }
  }
}

function decimalDisplay() {
  if (screen.innerHTML.includes('.')) {
    decimal.disabled;
  } else {
    screen.innerText += this.innerText;
  }
}

function buttonDisplay() {
  if (this.innerText != "*" &&
    this.innerText != "/" &&
    this.innerText != "+" &&
    this.innerText != "-" &&
    this.innerText != "=" &&
    this.innerText != "clear" &&
    this.innerText != "delete" &&
    this.innerText != ".") {
    screen.innerText += this.innerText;
  }
}

function add() {
  result = previousNum + currentNum;
  return previousNum + currentNum;

}

function subtract() {
  result = previousNum - currentNum;
  return previousNum - currentNum;
}

function multiply() {
  result = previousNum * currentNum;
  return previousNum * currentNum;
}

function divide() {
  result = previousNum / currentNum;
  return previousNum / currentNum;
}

function operate() {
  screen.innerText = (operand.reduce(chosenOperator));
  currentNum = result;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.screen {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>CALCULATOR</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="previous-operand"></div>
    <div class="current-operand"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" data-type="delete">delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-type="clear">clear</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" data-type="7">7</button>
    <button type="button">8</button>
    <button type="button">9</button>
    <button type="button" data-type="operator">/</button>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button">4</button>
      <button type="button">5</button>
      <button type="button">6</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="operator">*</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button">1</button>
      <button type="button">2</button>
      <button type="button">3</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="operator">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button">0</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="decimal">.</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="equals">=</button>
      <button type="button" data-type="operator">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: that's a long story; a bit of culture to start... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: you could always use `eval()` but that isn't recommended much for security reasons, but still, in your project it might be fine

Comment: @cornonthecob the resource i'm following recommended not to use it either for security purposes as well and so that learners can attempt to utilize the material learned - as a result I have longer code trying to find an alternative way